# What are good options for hosting video that give you privacy and control (not youtube or vimeo)?

Tags: web-hosting, video

I have used http://www.longtailvideo.com/bits-on-the-run,http://www.influxis.com/, wistia for video hosting. Wistia didn't allow the finer control that we wanted to have. Influxis doesn't have the features that Bits on the Run has but platform usage for BOTR gets expensive. I was thinking of moving the videos to Amazon CDN. What are your thoughts and experiences with video hosting and are there any recommendations? Videos will be privately streamed to 100's of doctors offices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind paying, there's always [Vzaar](http://vzaar.com/). Last company I worked for used them a lot and it didn't seem too expensive.

Answer (score 2):

Not all of these apply, but you could also take a look at these:

- livestream
- Ustream
- justin.tv
- blogtv
- vodpod
- hulu (ent)
- kaltura (foss|commercial)
- metacafe
- monetizemedia
- Brightcove
- Kyte
- BestTV (--Brightcove reseller)
- vbrick (--ent)
- kit digital (ent)

These are from my personal notes. The "ent" means the service is aimed at the enterprise market only; "foss" means it's [Free and Open Source Software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_open_source_software); and the "--" just means I didn't like the site much.